# Extract an int from a file using multiple delimiters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file:

```
  90,-5 ,, 37  ,  1  99
  0 -55,,,
  ,,,11
```

I need to extract the integers into an array.
I have been traing to do so with this code:

```
File file=new File("2.txt");
Scanner in=new Scanner(file);
in.useDelimiter(" *|,*|\\n");
int[] b=new int[20];
int i=0;
while(in.hasNextInt()){
  b[i]=in.nextInt();
  i++;  
              }
  in.close();
```

What i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error? Does the code not compile? Is the output wrong?

Comment: what is the outcome of this program?

Comment: The line `Scanner in = new Scanner(file)` might throw a `FileNotFoundException`. Maybe the issue is that you are not catching it, or throwing it further.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the delimiter expression and the separator characters. In this case, it is simpler to match the characters in which you *are* interested rather then separator characters. A precompiled [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) can be used for greater performance.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("2.txt"));
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and there is one issue: negative integers are added to the array as positive integers.

Comment: Yep, the use of pipe `|` delimited delimiter list is somewhat mind-numbing. -updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to read the documentation on patterns, because in a quick brush through now it doesn't look like `|` is the union operator. Also, wouldn't `\\n` be a literal backslash n, not the newline character?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)